# NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord despite having the application_record file correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I am having trouble using my actual models, I am getting the following error when trying to create a user:

```
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)
```

I do have the following file in models/application_record.rb

which looks like:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

When I change the User class to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base instead, I get the same error, except for ActiveRecord.

My application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

    config.load_defaults 6.1

    config.generators.system_tests = nil
  end
```

I am using Rails 6.1.

My Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'activerecord'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

What is happening? I have no spelling mistakes, the model is user.rb, I can't figure out what's going on.

All of the advice I have found

Comment: Got cut off - all fo the advice I have found is just telling to add the file that I already have.

Comment: Assuming your `user.rb` contains `class User < ApplicationRecord`. Would you like to also share that in case there is something obvious?

Do you also have, in your `config/application.rb` the usual `require_relative "boot"`,  `require "rails"` `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` etc etc before the module definition?

Comment: Yes, I had everything written correctly, I came back to say I figured it out. 

I was running a task that took a .txt file as input using STDIN, and although I remembered to require the models, I completely forgot to actually load the rails environment. THIS solved it: `require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/config/environment.rb"`

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone is running into this problem, and you have the files you need, check to see if you're loading the rails environment. I added:

`require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/config/environment.rb"`

to the top of the file I was running *where I was calling the classes* and that solved the problem.

Comment: So were you running the files directly from the command line using ruby? Seems odd that the rails server or your test suite would not be autoloading the environment. Just determining context for any future readers.